# Why DataGridView doesn't update when bounded DataTable is updated?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, copy

i have a DataGridView connected to a DataTable by a BindingSource object like this:

```
BindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;

DGV.DataSource = BindingSource;
```

If I modify the content of the DataTable element by element the DataGridView updates fine. However in my application I need to copy an existing DataTable to myDataTable.

```
DataTable tmp = myDataTable.Copy();

"Here i edit tmp DataTable's elements"

myDataTable = tmp.Copy();
```

If i do this DataGridView doesn't shows the new data, even if i saw with a breakpoint that the data in myDataTable are updated correctly.
Does anyone have any idea for this behavior?
Many Thanks

Comment: Re-assign the DataTable to the BindingSource. Maybe you could describe the reason why you make a copy of that same DataTable.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for the answer. Since the data in the DataTable are updated very rapidly (every 200ms) this cause the DataGridView to blink. For this reason i was trying to reduce this blinking writing just one time a copy of the DataTable instead of writing every single value with a for.